# Numpy randint not really random?

Tags: python, random

The situation: I have a big dataset with more than 18 million examples.
I train several models and want to track the accuracy.

When forwarding all examples and computing accuracy this is approximately 83 percent. But this takes a long time.

So I try to sample a small subset of the whole dataset and compute accuracy for that. I expect to see approximately the same number (around 80 percent)

```
total = 4096
N = dataset.shape[0]
indices = np.random.randint(N-1, size=total)
batch = dataset[indices,:]
```

However, now the output looks like this, when running it for 10 'random' batches:

```
> satisfied 4096/4096
> 1.0 satisfied 4095/4096
> 0.999755859375 satisfied 4095/4096
> 0.999755859375 satisfied 4094/4096
> 0.99951171875 satisfied 4095/4096
> 0.999755859375 satisfied 4095/4096
> 0.999755859375 satisfied 4094/4096
> 0.99951171875 satisfied 4096/4096
> 1.0 satisfied 4095/4096
> 0.999755859375 satisfied 4096/4096
> 1.0
```

So here it performs always way too good and seems to only almost only sample from the 80 percent good examples. What can I do to make it really random, such that it gives a good view of the accuracy?

This makes also the training go wrong, because for the next training batch only the good examples are sampled.

EDIT: so this is not about the training itself! I have a trained model with 83 percent accuracy. I use only this model for testing accuracy. When testing accuracy on small subsets it gives always 99 or 100 percent, even for 100 random batches.

Edit:
And the code I generate the output with that gets 99 or 100 percent

```
def constraints_satisfied_v3(sess, model, dataset, pointclouds, instructions, trajectories, distances, is_training=0):
    satisfied = 0
    total = 4096

    # Pick random examples
    N = dataset.shape[0]

    indices = np.random.randint(N-1, size=total)

    batch = dataset[indices,:]     
    pdb.set_trace()
    # Fill a feed dictionary with the actual set of images and labels
    feed_dict = {model.input_pointcloud: pointclouds[batch[:,0],:],
                 model.input_language: instructions[batch[:,1],:],
                 model.input_traj: trajectories[batch[:,2],:],
                 model.input_traj_mv: trajectories[batch[:,3],:],
                 model.distances: distances[batch[:,2], batch[:,3]],
                 model.is_training: is_training}

    loss_value,emb_pl,emb_t,emb_t_mv,sim_mv,sim = sess.run([model.loss,model.embeddings_pl,model.embeddings_t,model.embeddings_t_mv,model.sim_mv,model.sim],
                                         feed_dict=feed_dict)

    result = np.greater_equal(sim, distances[batch[:,2], batch[:,3]]+sim_mv)
    satisfied = satisfied + np.sum(result)

    print 'satisfied %d/%d' % (satisfied, total)
    percentage = float(satisfied)/float(total)
    #pdb.set_trace()
    return percentage
```

Edit: Okay, you have a point. When training batches are sampled the same way the model is only trained on that data. On that is why it is doing almost perfect on that data. But the issue stays how to sample from the whole dataset

So this is the version that get 83 percent accuracy

```
def constraints_satisfied_v2(sess, model, dataset, pointclouds, instructions, trajectories, distances, is_training=0):
    satisfied = 0
    total = 0


    N = dataset.shape[0]

    #indices = np.random.randint(N-1, size=int(total))
    #batch = dataset[indices,:]     
    i = 10000
    while i < N:
        indices = np.arange(i-10000, i)
        if i+10000 < N:        
            i = i+10000
        else:
            i = N   
        batch = dataset[indices,:] 
        # Fill a feed dictionary with the actual set of images and labels
        feed_dict = {model.input_pointcloud: pointclouds[batch[:,0],:],
                     model.input_language: instructions[batch[:,1],:],
                     model.input_traj: trajectories[batch[:,2],:],
                     model.input_traj_mv: trajectories[batch[:,3],:],
                     model.distances: distances[batch[:,2], batch[:,3]],
                     model.is_training: is_training}

        loss_value,emb_pl,emb_t,emb_t_mv,sim_mv,sim = sess.run([model.loss,model.embeddings_pl,model.embeddings_t,model.embeddings_t_mv,model.sim_mv,model.sim],
                                         feed_dict=feed_dict)

        result = np.greater_equal(sim, distances[batch[:,2], batch[:,3]]+sim_mv)
        satisfied = satisfied + np.sum(result)
        total = total + batch.shape[0]
        print 'satisfied %d/%d' % (satisfied, total)
    percentage = float(satisfied)/float(total)
    return percentage
```

Edit: it seems the difference between constraints_satisfied_v2 and constraints_satisfied_v3 has to do with the use of batch normalization. In v3 random samples are picked which correspond to training mean and std statistics, thus high performance. In v2 the data is not in a random order, which makes the mean and std not very representative

Comment: Could you also include the code you're generating that output with? That would be helpful.

Comment: Numpy's RNG is fine. This is a problem of your learning-approach. As you did not give any information at all, i suppose it's a learning-algorithm which has a high model-complexity and overfits on the small sample-size. This calls for regulization or increasing sample-size. There are also many more parameters behaving differently when the dataset changes.

Comment: You want to pick 256 indices, but ```size=total=4096```?

Comment: Yes, smaller or bigger batch sizes doesnot make a difference

Comment: It's really hard to help here. Training-code is missing, also a lot of information on how you obtained the results. Well... increase batch-size to total data-size and see if it's 100% or 83% or something else. If it's not 83%, you are comparing different accuracy-calculations obviously.

Comment: I included the two functions, the one that gives 99 or 100 percent accuracy with a random batch and the other one which looks at the complete dataset and get 83 percent

Answer (score 0):

This has to do nothing with randomness, to my mind, and NumPy's `random` is perfectly fine.

In this answer I'm assuming you're training some sort of a *neural network*, abbreviated as *ANN* (Artificial Neural Network) here.

The problem is, it's almost always easier to 'understand' common patterns in a small batch of objects than in a large one. That's how our brain works and that's how ANNs work as well. Although it doesn't mean that what your ANN has 'understood' from a smaller batch applies to any other collection of objects of the same nature.

For example, you can teach the computer to distinguish between cats and dogs on photos using 6 photos of cats and 7 - of dogs. Now, when you give it a photo of a cat it has never seen before, it may fail to tell anything specific because *it has not 'seen' enough cats and dogs*, it was unable to *generalize*.

They can also simply memorize the data and give you fascinating accuracy on the training set but fail horribly on test data.

So, this is a very important and difficult problem of ANNs, which you may try to solve... by increasing the number of objects in a set, thus allowing the computer *to generalize*.

Comment: While not very scientific (which may be important to discuss it), i would argue that it's quite the opposite of ```The problem is, it's almost always easier to 'understand' common patterns in a small batch of objects than in a large one.``` But i share your reading of some high-complexity classifier behaving differently on small data-sets.

Comment: I made an edit, this has nothing to do with training the model. I used an already trained model.

Comment: @Derk, did you train the model on the data you're using for accuracy checking? It could've memorized some of this data and be just spitting the copies of correct answers.

Comment: See my edits, I have trained a lot of neural networks and the problem here is that it seems the network is not seeing all the data during training (and during validation on small batches the same issue occurs)